# Xamarin Android - no flowlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin

I want to display several widgets with dynamic size in a flowlayout fashion, but I can't seem to find a flowlayout. Is it really no flowlayout in Xamarin for Android as part of the framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came across this implementation

http://slodge.blogspot.no/2013/01/an-mono-for-android-wrappanelflowlayout.html

which suits my needs perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

No,there is not flowlayout in Xamarin  Android as far as I know.

Comment: well that sucks... wouldn't know how to implement one?

Comment: I had a similar problem, I needed a DataGridView  ,but there is not in Xamarin . After searching a lot for the best solution, I created a table layout and I played for a long time with it until it looked like a DataGridView. So,I think you can try the other layouts supported that are in Xamarin ,and trying to adjust it as you like.

Comment: I think Linear Layout is ok for you, it has vertical and horizontal orientation.

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin Android  `FlowLayout` available. Install nuget package AndroidFlowLayout by Dennis Daume. Make xaml like this

```
<org.apmem.tools.layouts.FlowLayout
android:id="@+id/ControlPanel"
android:padding="0dp"
android:includeFontPadding="false"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Aceess your flow layout in .cs page & add controls as many you need. Even your can add controls from xaml too.

```
var flaout = view.FindViewById<FlowLayout>(Resource.Id.ControlPanel);
foreach (var item in SenderData)
{
    var checkbox = new CheckBox(Context);
    checkbox.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Resource.Color.DimGray, 0, 0, 0);
    checkbox.Id = Convert.ToInt32(mailList.Value);
    checkbox.Text=item.Name
    checkbox.ScaleY = 0.8f;
    checkbox.ScaleX = 0.9f;
    flaout.AddView(checkbox);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also this from Jason Smith from Xamarin, for Xamarin.Forms:

[WrapLayout.cs](https://github.com/conceptdev/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Evolve13/Evolve13/Controls/WrapLayout.cs)

It's the code from [this talk from Xamarin Evolve 16](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/custom/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is called the `FlexLayout`, introduced with Xamarin.Forms version 3.0:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout