# More textviews in multiple lines

Tags: android, xamarin

I've searched for this but after a while I can not find the solution. I have three TextViews in one horizontal LinearLayout, but the text does not goes in multiple lines but look like this:

[image]

I found that in android there is a component FlowLayout but I can't find something similar for Xamarin. Do you have any suggestions, or some native Java code that will work for Xamarin. Thanks in advance.

**Here is the code:**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:text="dora sareva"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#8289A6"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:text="reacted to your recording reacted to your recording"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="First reading practice"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Tried `android:orientation="vertical"`?

Comment: yes and they are in separate vertical lines which is not what I need, I have to get a look like is the same sentence

Comment: check this out https://github.com/DefinitelyBound/xamarin-android/tree/master/android-flowlayout i don't know about Xmarin much. but it might help you.

Comment: @merian: then I think it is impossible to do this. You could make one `TextView` and set the text of equal to `text1 + text2 + text3`.

Comment: As I mentioned there is no component as Flaylayout in Xamarin, but thanks anyway

Comment: check this out too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18433278/xamarin-android-no-flowlayout

Comment: @Merian Try the my answer and revert me whether its working or not

Comment: @chiru nope it is not working as I said I have to get a look like is the same sentence

Comment: @Merian is it necessary to take Three TextView?

Comment: @Merian, i misread your title and question. Why dont you try like as pauwelyn said. Dynamic Text appending on single textview

Comment: @Merian you need different textview for different text style and size, then use spannable string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our Java code add this:

```
 final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.text_sample)));
```

In your String.xml file add this

```
<string name="text_sample"><![CDATA[  dora sareva <font color=\'#8289A6\'>reacted to your recording</font>reacted to your recording First reading practice]]></string>
```

And add this only in your xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="@string/text_sample"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```